# dbcontext.SaveChanges(); not updating when replacing model

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, entities

I have a problem with Entity Framework 6.

I'm trying to update an existing entity, but I'd like to entirely replace it instead of updating every single property one by one. When I replace a property and call `SaveChanges()`, it saves to the database just fine, however if I want to simply replace the whole object, it does nothing.

The commented-out part below would work obviously, but when I try to replace the object (in my case the `ninja.ToModel()` object, which comes from a Ninja view model) it does not work.

Obviously I'm missing something, I think it has to do with `Attach()`, but so far everything I've found on the internet only confused me. What's the right approach to entirely update an object like I want?

```
public void SaveNinja()
{
    using (var context = new ManagerEntities())
    {
        Ninja nin = context.Ninjas.Find(ninja.ToModel().Id);

        // nin.Name = ninja.Name;
        // nin.Strength = ninja.Strength;
        // nin.Agility = ninja.Agility;
        // nin.Intelligence = ninja.Intelligence;
        // nin.Gold = ninja.Gold;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line only *finds* a `Ninja` object that matches the `Id` you're passing. It obviously does not update the found object's properties, since you're not telling it to do so.

```
Ninja nin = context.Ninjas.Find(ninja.ToModel().Id);
```

If you don't want to set object properties one by one, you can have a public method that does so.

```
public class Ninja
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void SetNinja(Ninja ninja)
    {
        Id = ninja.Id;
        Name = ninja.Name;
    }
}
```

Then call it when you find the object:

```
Ninja nin = context.Ninjas.Find(ninja.ToModel().Id);
nin.SetNinja(ninja);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. That being said, I had to make a SetNinja() method in the ViewModel instead of directly in the Model itself, but the idea is the same and worked.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you load in a model instance, you should just change the values and save it.  You don't want the database to recognize two instances representing the same model data.

However, if you aren't loading anything from the database, and you're making this entirely yourself to replace the database entry, then you'll need to do two things to make that work:

1. Make sure the primary ID field (looks like you've called it `Id` here) is set the same as the object to be replaced.
2. Before saving, do this:

   ```
   db.Attach(ninja).State = EntityStates.Modified;
   ```

   That code snippet does two things. First, it attaches the database to the object (essentially telling it "this is the instance of this model you should use").
   Then, second, it sets the `State` to `Modified`, which tells the database it needs to be written back to the disk when `SaveChanges()` is called.